# SQL Server OpenQuery to Exec command

Tags: sql-server

The following query is working fine in SQL Server 2008 R2

```
select * 
from openquery(LinkedServerName, 'exec databaseName.dbo.SP_GET_INFO');
```

I'm trying to convert it using exec command, but no luck.

For instance:

```
exec ('call databaseName.dbo.SP_GET_INFO') at LinkedServerName
```

Always getting a syntax error with this message:

> Could not execute statement on remote server 'LinkedServerName'

Thanks.

Comment: `exec ('exec databaseName.dbo.SP_GET_INFO') at LinkedServerName`

Comment: Thanks @lad2025, but I´m getting this error:
OLE DB provider "STREAM" for linked server "(null)" returned message "The operation of multi-step OLE DB generated errors. Check the status values of OLE DB if available. No work was done."

Comment: Does your stored procedure return XML/TEXT/Image or so on?

Comment: Hi.
The stored procedure only contains a select statement.

Comment: But what types it returns?

Comment: int types only. This is the sql sentence:
select [id] from [database].[dbo].[table];

Sorry if I misunderstand you.

Comment: Check Linked Server settings and `RPC/RPC OUT/Promote Distributed Transactions` are set to `true`

Comment: Yes. Those options are set to true

Comment: Excuse me @lad2025
It works fine using the sentence in which only the id column is selected, but when I change it to * (select all columns), it fails. What should I do?

Comment: Try `SELECT col_name1, col_name2, ...`

Comment: There is a ntext type column in the sentence that returns null. With the other columns it's ok. Do you know the reason?

Comment: Try with your NTEXT column sth like `CAST(col_name_ntext AS NVARCHAR(MAX))`

Comment: returns OLE DB provider "STREAM" for linked server "(null)"

Comment: try `AS NVARCHAR(1000)`

Comment: that works!. But in the case I have a table with ntext columns I have to reduce column length?

Comment: I guess your driver can handle max NVARCHAR(4000) try it, so it will be truncated, see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175970%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: It works too. So, to prevent issues like this one, it depends on the driver I used to create the linked server. I'll try with another one to see the results.
Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @lad2025 for the great help.

Using the following script will work:

```
exec ('databaseName.dbo.SP_GET_INFO') at LinkedServerName
```

The first time I tested the code it did not work because of the driver I used to create the linked server.
I have used "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers". With this one I got the  error:

> OLE DB provider "STREAM" for linked server "(null)" returned message ...

The reason was because in the stored procedure I do a select on a nText column which has null values.

So, I changed the driver to "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server" and the script worked fine.

Hope this helps someone else.